# What is the meaning of local speech synthesizer in TTS APIs

Tags: text-to-speech

I have tried all the methods and routines on the stackoverflow so far to get the TTS working for voice values with lang: "hi-IN", name: "Google हिन्दी" voiceURI: "Google हिन्दी" but no luck so far.
The one thing I observed in list of 21 languages shown in array of getVoices() 
Microsoft David Desktop - English (United States) and
Microsoft Zira Desktop - English (United States) 
has local service property set to true. and *David's* default value is true. Rest all 19 entries have both values set as false. Is this the reason for not getting it required language (Hindi) voice. Is there any additional setting or plug in required? Any help will is highly appreciated.

Comment: 1. Please show us your code. 2. Are you saying it always speaks using the 'David' voice?

Comment: It means that it is installed locally on the device.

Comment: @some, how to check in device? and if value is false means it is not installed then how to install?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic example:

```js
// Load voices
let voices = [];
if (speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged !== undefined) {
  speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged = () => {
    voices = speechSynthesis.getVoices()
  };
}
voices = speechSynthesis.getVoices();

// Function to build and speak utterance
const speak = () => {
  const msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance('1, 2, 3');
  msg.voice = voices.find(v => v.lang === 'hi-IN');
  msg.lang = 'hi-IN';
  msg.onerror = (e) => {console.log('Error', e)};
  speechSynthesis.cancel();
  speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
}

// Speak upon clicking button
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.querySelector('#speak').addEventListener('click', () => {
    speak();
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>57990014</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="57990014.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <button type="button" id="speak">Speak</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Does it speak in English? Try with this revised speak function:

```
const speak = () => {
  const msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance('1, 2, 3');
  msg.onerror = (e) => {console.log('Error', e)};
  speechSynthesis.cancel();
  speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
}
```

Comment: Are you running it from this page? Are you clicking the 'Speak' button? What's your OS/browser combination? Does your device make sound from something else e.g. YouTube?

Comment: @SSS There's a change to the code to issue a cancel; sometimes speechSynthesis gets jammed and this will fix that.

Comment: Yes, my machine is able to play all the sounds. OS is Windows 10, Browser Chrome Version 77.0.3865.90 (Official Build) (64-bit). Tried with updated code as well.

Comment: I have created the HTML page out of the snippet provided, saved locally and run on Chorme

Comment: Run it from this page: the blue button "Run code snippet".

Comment: Yes, I did it before creating another local HTML. I got the issue I think check answer posted. below.

Comment: @SSS Have added a line to log an error to console. Run it to see what the error is.

Comment: added the line you have added and it does not report any error.

Comment: @SSS Swap out the speak function with that above. I asked before if it speaks in English but you didn't answer. If it doesn't speak in English using the substitute function try clearing Chrome's cache.

Comment: After swap of the speak function it speaks English.

Comment: Try clearing he cache anyway. I'm assuming you're connected to the internet?

Answer (score 0):

I think, I got the issue. The windows system should have required language along with speech installed. Otherwise it will not work. I am facing some issue with installing language from settings but will update once done and tested successfully.